# Microsoft Teams Graph API - Invalid bind property name owners in request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata, microsoft-teams

I'm currently having major issues with creating teams from the Graph API.  I was initially trying to create teams based on groups, however I have found out today that you can now create a team without creating a group first then waiting 15 minutes to then create the team from the following link.  This would make things considerably simpler.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0

I am using the Microsoft.Graph SDK (v3.12.0 released 26th Aug) so replicated the http call using the SDK as follows.

```
        var team = new Team
        {
            DisplayName = "My Group Name",
            Description = "My Group Description",
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('educationClass')"},
                {"owners@odata.bind", $"[\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('{usersGuid}')\"]"}
            },
        };

        var response = await _graphClient.Teams
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(team);
```

The code above gives a:

```
[16:14:01 ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Status Code: BadRequest
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: BadRequest
Message: Invalid bind property name owners in request.
```

If I remove the line

```
{"owners@odata.bind", $"[\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('{usersGuid}')\"]"}
```

from the code I get the following:

```
ErrorMessage : {"errors":[{"message":"A team owner must be provided when creating a team in application context."}]
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: This post can help you to use the correct syntax for odata.bind - http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2018/11/create-azure-ad-groups-with-initial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v1.0 the owners relationship is not currently present, so you have to use the beta endpoint.
`POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams`

with the following body format

`{ "template@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')", "displayName":"Test Team", "description":"Test description", "owners@odata.bind":["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user guid}"] }`

Note: the user guid should also be bare, i.e without the brackets and quotes in your example.