# Create a Team with owner (Application Permissions)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The documentation (example 2) on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0) states that to specify an owner when creating a team an 'owners@odata.bind' property should be added to the POST.

The example shows a body of:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
  "displayName": "My Sample Team",
  "description": "My Sample Team’s Description",
  "owners@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('userId')"
  ]
}
```

Trying that out in Graph Explorer (with a valid userId) results in a **`BadRequest`** error with a message of ***`Invalid bind property name owners in request`***

Is this a bug? If not then what is the correct way to specify the owner when creating a team.

NOTE: I know there are other methods of creating a team (create group then convert etc), but this question is specifically about POSTing to the `/teams` endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the call works correctly on the `beta` version of the endpoint it does not yet work on the `v1.0` version endpoint.

I raised the issue with Microsoft and they confirmed it was an issue and raised a bug for it. I also reported it in the Microsoft docs, that the example provided does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I use the `v1.0` version, I will encounter the same error as you, just change it to the `beta` version.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Carl, I was specifically looking for a solution for the `v1.0` version.

Comment: @KennetRunner   Unfortunately, In v1.0 the owners relationship is not currently present, so you have to use the beta endpoint. I noticed that there is a problem similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63620447/microsoft-teams-graph-api-invalid-bind-property-name-owners-in-request